# Can`t take value from html textarea to php variable

Tags: php, html, post, get, textarea

I made a blogging platform and I have an ajax updated page where I can select which article to display and his comments and add comments. When I leave a comment it takes the logged user info, the article on which the comment has been made but the comment value is not taken to store it in the database. This is the code :

```html
<div align="center">
  <h3>Comentarii:</h3>
  <form method="POST">
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="comentariu" placeholder="Comenteaza">
        </textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit"><br>
    <hr>
  </form>
</div>
```

```
<?php
  $comnou = $_POST['comentariu'];
  $comuser = $_SESSION['user'];
  $conadaugacom = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "blog");
  $sqladaugacom = "insert into comentarii (continut_comentarii, 
  user_comentarii, articol_comentarii) values ('$comnou', '$comuser', '$ta')";
  mysqli_query($conadaugacom, $sqladaugacom);
  mysqli_close($conadaugacom);
?>
```

AJAX Code ->

```js
function showUser(str) {
  if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  } else {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "getuser.php?q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
}
```

Comment: is `$ta` defined elsewhere? This is wide open to sql injection btw

Comment: You are missing to show the Ajax part

Comment: I inserted the ajax part

Comment: You are using `get` but read `post`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that before **POST** request serialize the data from form.

html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div align="center">
  <h3>Comentarii:</h3>
  <form method="POST">
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="comentariu" placeholder="Comenteaza">
        </textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit"><br>
    <hr>
  </form>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
<script>
     $('input').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var data = $('form').serialize();
        $.ajax({
           url: 'your_url_to_post.php',
           data: data,
           success: function(response){

           },
           type: 'POST'
        });
     });
</script>
```

php file

add this line to check **comentariu** not empty

```
if(isset($_POST['comentariu'])){
     $comentariu = $_POST['comentariu];
}
```

Comment: Please answer a few questions until you have the 50 rep needed to comment. This is not an answer.

Comment: i know i am new here

Comment: NOW it’s an answer

Comment: You however assume jQuery

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19143169)

Comment: @Chris it is an answer. No longer a comment